# Does weak convergence imply time average convergence?

Tags: integration, limits, probability-limit-theorems

I was reading some lecture notes for Poisson processes, in which after proving the following,

$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}P(X(t)=j) = e^{-\rho}\frac{\rho^j}{j!}$

it states that this implies convergence in a time average sense as well:

$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tP(X(s)=j)ds = e^{-\rho}\frac{\rho^j}{j!}$

Intuitively, it seems fine to me. Only what happens at large values of $t$ matters to us when computing long run time average. However, how should I go about proving this formally?

Comment: If the probability is not a function of $t$ then it is a constant in regards to the integration.

Comment: @copper.hat but probability is a function of $t$. Only when $t$ goes to infinity does it converge to something that is not a function of $t$ (obviously)

Comment: Sorry, I must have been inhaling something unusual when I wrote that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't really about probability since we can just define $f(s) = \mathbb{P}(X(s) = j)$.  Then we are given that $\displaystyle{\lim_{s \to \infty} f(s) = c}$ for some constant $c$.

We are asked to prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(s)ds = c}$.  This is true for any bounded $f$.  (Clearly $f$ is a bounded function since it is a probability).  As you say, only large values of $t$ matter.  For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $u$ such that $|f(s) - c| < \varepsilon$ for $s > u$.  Then just divide the domain of integration into the intervals $[0,u]$ and $[u,t]$.